# Cannot get output from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure which returns me the identity of the added row, as below:

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_CONTACT_EXTRANET_CLIENT
 (
@NumCRPCEN nvarchar (255),
@nomContact nvarchar (255),
@prenomContact nvarchar (255),
@telFixe nvarchar (255),
@telPort nvarchar (255),
@mailContact nvarchar(255),
@idPhysique int output
)
as 
Begin
    INSERT INTO T_Physique values (.....)
    SET @idPhysique = @@IDENTITY
    RETURN @idPhysique
End
```

Now I would like to get the output in ADO.NET and I've tried a lot of things but the last one is :

```
Requeteadd.Parameters.Add("@idPhysique", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            Requeteadd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int IdPhysique = (int)Requeteadd.Parameters["@idPhysique"].Value;
```

But it shows me an error where it says that returned value is null. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: The @@IDENTITY function returns the last Identity value generated in your session.  Since you didn't generate any, NULL is returned.

Comment: Yes but when i write that : `Select @@IDENTITY as Id` instead of `SET @idPhysique = @@IDENTITY RETURN @idPhysique` and delete the paramater @idPhysique as an output from the parameters list, it shows me the right value

Comment: Take the RETURN out. It sets the Proc's return status and may be messing up ADO.net.

Comment: Hi, I dont see any problem with your given code. You should get desired result. I did it many times in many environment.

Comment: I've answered at my question just at the end of the topic, take a look !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @RBarryYoung said, the solution is as below:

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_CONTACT_EXTRANET_CLIENT
(
@NumCRPCEN nvarchar (255),
@nomContact nvarchar (255),
@prenomContact nvarchar (255),
@telFixe nvarchar (255),
@telPort nvarchar (255),
@mailContact nvarchar(255),
@idPhysique int output
)
as 
Begin
    INSERT INTO T_Physique values (1, @nomContact, @prenomContact, (Select AdrLngId from T_Adresse where AdrStrRC = '74003'), 'T', 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '*', @telFixe, @telPort, null, null, null, 1, @mailContact, null, null, null, null, null)
    SET @idPhysique = @@IDENTITY

End 
RETURN @idPhysique
```

the return of the output has to be after the End. For information, in ADO.NET c#, I'm getting the returned value by doing this :

```
Requeteadd.Parameters.Add("@idPhysique", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            Requeteadd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int IdPhysique = (int)Requeteadd.Parameters["@idPhysique"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `RETURN` to output data - this is for error / status codes, and is limited to `INT`, so as soon as you need to "return" other data types, you need to do something different. You have an output parameter, so why not use it? Also, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, not `@@IDENTITY`, since the latter can be affected by triggers and not necessarily give you the identity value you just generated. Finally, [always use the schema prefix when creating / referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and [never use the `sp_` prefix](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). You can use `usp_` instead but what values does this add, really?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ADD_CONTACT_EXTRANET_CLIENT
  @NumCRPCEN nvarchar (255),
  @nomContact nvarchar (255),
  @prenomContact nvarchar (255),
  @telFixe nvarchar (255),
  @telPort nvarchar (255),
  @mailContact nvarchar(255),
  @idPhysique int output
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.T_Physique values (.....);
    SET @idPhysique = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```